# Как возможно реализовать следующий функционал при помощи php?

Tags: javascript, php, json

Создайте класс, который будет работать с `json` файлом, который хранит в себе данные людей - `ФИО`, `возраст`, `профессия`.
Реализуйте возможность, как указать файл при создании экземпляра класса, так и указать файл  позже. Обработайте обращение к методам, если данные не переданы.
Помимо указанного, должны быть реализованы следующие методы:
-получения списка людей;
-добавления нового человека;
-удаление человека по указанию одного или нескольких полей (например, удалить всех, кому 30 лет | удалить Иванов Иван Иванович, возраст 53, слесарь и т.п.);
-очистка данных;
-запись данных в файл;

Comment: воспользуйтесь, например, текстовым редактором.

Comment: Если это ТЗ - то Вы ошиблись сайтом, нужно на фриланс. Если где-то ошибка - напишите кусок кода и Вам подскажут

Comment: "Здесь предлагать выполнить работу за вас и наоборот — моветон." - [/help](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ведь это обычное CRUD php приложение, только вместо базы данных у вас есть JSON файл, вы можете найти и адаптировать любой пример CRUD под свою задачу, [например](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2014/06/php-object-oriented-crud-example-oop.html)